# MySQL subtract two similar rows and multiply results by another row

Tags: mysql, sum, distinct

I want to be able to subtract the qty of ondemand to reserved from the same zone, type and os and then multiply the remaining qty by the rate.

Here is a sample dump of the mysql data

```
| Zone  | Type  | Qty | OS    | Reservation | Rate  |
| zone1 | type1 | 12  | linux | ondemand    | 0.24  |
| zone1 | type1 | 6   | linux | reserved    | 0.056 |
| zone1 | type2 | 3   | linux | ondemand    | 0.82  |
| zone2 | type1 | 5   | mswin | ondemand    | 0.24  |
| zone2 | type1 | 2   | mswin | reserved    | 0.056 |
| zone2 | type2 | 3   | linux | ondemand    | 0.82  |
| zone3 | type1 | 4   | linux | ondemand    | 0.24  |
| zone3 | type1 | 1   | linux | reserved    | 0.056 |
```

The result would be

```
| Zone  | Type  | Qty | OS    | Reservation | Rate  | sum() |
| zone1 | type1 | 6   | linux | ondemand    | 0.24  | 1.44  |
| zone1 | type1 | 6   | linux | reserved    | 0.056 | 0.336 |
| zone1 | type2 | 3   | linux | ondemand    | 0.82  | 0.246 |
| zone2 | type1 | 3   | mswin | ondemand    | 0.24  | 0.72  |
| zone2 | type1 | 2   | mswin | reserved    | 0.056 | 0.112 |
| zone2 | type2 | 3   | linux | ondemand    | 0.82  | 0.246 |
| zone3 | type1 | 3   | linux | ondemand    | 0.24  | 0.72  |
| zone3 | type1 | 1   | linux | reserved    | 0.056 | 0.056 |
```

I am not sure how to get a distinct statement to work with this.  I don't know if this is possible with mysql or if I would need to script it and then produce the output.  Any help is appreciated.

There isn't always a corresponding reserved in the zone for a type and os that contains an ondemand.

Comment: so the rate to use is the ondemand rate, not the reserved rate?

Comment: The rate to use is the corresponding rate in the table, I like your answer however it is only taking in account ondemand rate and is excluding the reserved. I need it to be able to calculate the number of ondemand with the reserved as well... What you gave me is very close to what I need I will see if I can get it to work.

Comment: My sum statement should have said sum(qty*rate) I think you assumed that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the table to itself:

```
select
    t1.Zone, t1.Type, t1.Qty - ifnull(t2.Qty, 0), t1.OS,
    t1.rate, (t1.Qty - ifnull(t2.Qty, 0)) * t1.rate as total
from mytable t1
left join mytable t2
    on t1.zone = t2.zone
    and t1.type = t2.type
    and t1.os = t2.os
    and t2.reservation = 'reserved'
```

and t1.reservation = 'ondemand'

Ihe critical kung fu is the last condition in the join condition. It ensures there is only a join for the "ondemand" rows - with a `left join`, all other row types (and those "ondenand" rows without a corresponding "reserved" row) will get a null for there join qty value (hence the `ifnull()` to give them a zero to work with).

Note that this will correctly calculate the total even if there are no matching "reserved" rows for the "ondemand" rows.

To be honest, I've never seen this kind of query before where only *some* of the rows from the parent side are joined to, but *all* rows are kept.

Comment: Very close to what I am looking for however this is excluding reserved and the reserved rate.  I need it to just subtract the reserved qty from the ondemand qty and then calculate the total rate for ondemand and reserved.  Hope that makes sense sorry a bit confusing.....

Comment: No sorry. I don't understand you. This query subtracts the reserved from the ondemand, so that part is correct, yes? But I don't understand the rate part. Can you give more details - maybe an example? (I gtg now. LEave a comment explaining the rate and I'll look back in several hours)

Comment: Is there some sort of grouping required? Because your sample data has no such groups: All the sample data is unique for `zone, type, os`. If grouping is required, please show an example of how you want the calculation done via sample data

Comment: I don't need to group and yes the unique would be for the zone, type and os.  However I will need the corresponding rate to the reservation (ondemand and reserved) but I need to subtract the qty of reserved from ondemand before calculating the total rate (qty*rate).

I will give your example another go maybe I was writing it incorrectly.  The example I gave is exactly what I need.

Comment: Very very sorry Bohemian, you are the man that was exactly what I was looking for but when I was retyping it into my actual tables I was forgetting the type on the join so I was getting real funky numbers.  Anyways thanks a lot that solved A LOT OF ISSUES!

Comment: Phew... I thought I was losing it :)

Comment: Gladly, that was super helpful, sorry a little new to stackoverflow the hints are always welcome

I got one more thing to do with this, say the results return negative values (ie there are more reserved then ondemand) how do I exclude the negative value results?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean "ignore"? Make zero, omit row entirely, don't perform subtraction, or other?

Comment: I would want to exclude it all together and or set the negative value to 0

Comment: I was thinking of doing a where statement on the 't1.qty - ifnull(t2.qty, 0) as total_qty' and at the end do a 'where 'total_qty' >= 0' but that doesn't work ......

Comment: That was it actually, I had to actually put 'where t1.qty - ifnull(t2.qty, 0) >= 0'

Comment: You can do that, or the [1337](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet) version of limiting subtraction to zero is `t1.qty - least(ifnull(t2.qty, 0), t1.qty)`. Cheers. btw - check out [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) where you can enter your schema and data and post a link in your question so people can try queries against your data easily, and even post the link back with their query running showing that it works.

Answer (score 0):

This has not been run, but something like this maybe?

```
select zone, type, os, ondemand_cnt, reserved_cnt, ondemand_cnt-reserved_cnt as cnt, 
<some_rate>*(ondemand_cnt-reserved_cnt) as calc_rate
from
(
select zone, type, os, sum(qty) as ondemand_cnt 
from table
where reservation = 'ondemand'
group by zone, type, os
) as o
join
(
select zone, type, os, sum(qty) as reserved_cnt
from table
where reservation = 'reserved'
group by zone, type, os
) as r on (o.zone = r.zone and o.type = r.type and o.os = r.os)
```